# Density and distribution functions exercise

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

***Exercise :***

*Let $X$ be a random variable and $f(x)$ the function :*

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
c, -4<x<0 \\
0.25, 2 < x < 4 & \\
0, \text{anywhere else} 
\end{cases}$$

***(a)*** Find such $c$, so that the function $f(x)$ is a density probability function of  $X$.

***(b)*** Find the distribution function of the random variable $X$.

***(c)*** Let a random sample $X_1, \dots, X_{100} $ be under the same distribution. Find the probability of their *Sample Mean* to be **no greater** than $1$.

***Solution-Attempt :***

***(a)*** For $f(x)$ to be a density probability function, it has to be :

$$\int_{-4}^{0}c dx =1 \Leftrightarrow \big[cx\big]_{-4}^0 = 1 \Leftrightarrow 4c = 1 \Leftrightarrow c = \frac{1}{4}= 0.25$$

So we have :

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0.25, -4<x<0 \\
0.25, 2 < x < 4 & \\
0, \text{anywhere else} 
\end{cases}$$

***(b)*** *Suppose that 
$X$ is a real-valued random variable. The (cumulative) distribution function of 
$X$ is the function $F$ given by :*

$$F(x) = P(X \le x), \quad x \in \mathbb R$$

Although I know this is the definition of the distribution function, I cannot seem how to produce it in this particular example, so I would really appreciatea thorough explanation.

I also know you can calculate the distribution function of a continuous random variable $X$ by :

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$$

for $- \infty < x <\infty$.

***(c)*** Cannot grasp on how to proceed for solving this one at all, so please elaborate thoroughly if possible.

Any help will be really, really appreciated. I missed most of the semester due to illness so I am doing my best to get my self ready for an upcoming exam and I'm trying to get all the help and knowledge possible.

Comment: For (a), the entire area under the distribution should be 1, and you are ignoring the part between 2 and 4.

Comment: By "Same Mean" I think your problem is saying "**sample** mean." If not it is probably a misprint in the problem, because question c is meaningless as it stands.

Comment: @Paul Yep, understood, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @MarkFischler Yes, I do mean "Sample Mean", it was a misprint. I would really appreciate a thorough solution at ***(b)*** and ***(c)*** .

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos Were you able to calculate the correct value of the constant c ?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos Were you able to apply the argument suggested in the accepted answer to solve (c)?

Comment: @Did Well I understood ***(a)*** and ***(b)*** 100%. Now for ***(c)*** I understood the work, though I did not continue on applying the argument to the calculation, since I am solving past exam questions (my time is really short).

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos Well, all I can say is that you should give it a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (a), as pointed out in a comment, you need the integral of the whole distribution to be $1$.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, dx = 
\int_{-\infty}^{-4} f(x)\, dx + \int_{-4}^0 f(x)\, dx + 
\int_{0}^2 f(x)\, dx + \int_{2}^4 f(x)\, dx + \int_{4}^\infty f(x)\, dx = \\
0+\int_{-4}^0 c\, dx +0+\int_{2}^4 \frac14\, dx+0= 4c+\frac12\\
 4c+\frac12 = 1 \implies c=\frac18
$$
For part (b), the easy way is indeed to use $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(x) \, dx$
but you can do it in pieces; in places where $f(x)=0$, the CDF does not grow. Thus

- $x<-4 \implies F(x) = 0$.
- $-4 \leq x < 0 \implies F(x) = c (x-(-4)) = \frac{x}8+\frac12$.
- $0 \leq x < 0 \implies F(x) = F(0) = \frac12$.
- $2 \leq x < 4 \implies F(x) = \frac12 + \frac14 (x-2) = \frac{x}4$.
- $x>4  \implies F(x) = F(4) = 1$.

For part (c), the sample mean $\hat{x}$ will be (by definition of mean) 
$$
\hat{x} = \frac1{100} \left( x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{99}+x_{100}\right)
$$
so we want to find 
$
P(\left( x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{99}+x_{100}\right) \leq 100\times 1 = 100.
$

Now let's say $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{99}= y$; then we would need to have 
$x_{100} \leq 100-y$.  But we know that is just $F(100-y)$ because that's exactly what the CDF tells you.

But what is $y$?  Well, a given value of $y$ could come about by quite a few possible combinations of the $x_n$, but whatever combination you have, it must be the case that $x_{99} = y-( x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{98})$. And so on down the line. 
In each case, we integrate probabilities using the pdf.

So the probability wanted is
$$
P\left( \sum_{n=1}^{100} x_n \leq 100 \right) = \\
\int_{x_1 = -\infty}^{\infty} f(x_1) 
\int_{x_2 = -\infty}^{\infty} f(x_2) 
\cdots
\int_{x_{99} = -\infty}^{\infty} f(x_{99}) F\left(100- \sum_{n=1}^{99} x_n\right) 
\, dx_{99} \,dx_{98} \cdots dx_1
$$
You can see how this is done by doing the integral over $dx_{99}$ first; that gives you a function of the first $98$ $x_n$s, and next you do the integral $dx_{98}$ and so forth.  You will see a pattern soon enough.

Comment: Is there a (relevant) typo at the third bullet ?

Comment: "You will see a pattern soon enough" Sorry but I do not get the argument at all. Are you saying that all the intermediate integrals and the complete one can be computed explicitely? I doubt that.